# How to get two elements of a JSON?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a file JSON with several elements. I want to retrieve this 2 variables in my webpage.

```
    "LIN":"",
    "LIB":"Droits de garde pour juillet 2021 Fundsettle",
    "ZON":"                2,60 EUR",
    "COL":""
```

My file JSON is on [Jsonblob](https://jsonblob.com/889781113971818496)

For now, I retrieve each element on my page, Instead of `Droits de garde pour juillet 2021 Fundsettle` and `2.60 EUR`.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6" *ngFor="let l of annexeDetails?.TAB; let i=index">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
         {{l.LIB}} 
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
         {{l.ZON}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
prepareDataForTemplate(res) {
    if (res.RETURNCODE == 'OKK00') {
        this.annexeDetails = res.JANX;

        console.log("Test" + JSON.stringify(this.annexeDetails));



    } else {
        if (res.RETURNLIST.length > 0) {
            this.errors = res.RETURNLIST;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

I think that the problem is my code HTML, but I am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(res.JANX.TAB[5].LIB)` and `console.log(res.JANX.TAB[5].ZON)`

Comment: @Weedoze: I retrieve correctly `Droits de garde pour juillet 2021 Fundsettle` and `2,60 EUR`.

Comment: @Weedoze: How to put this in HTML, please?

Comment: I don't have the angular knowledge but you already have what you need in a variable. You just need to display it where you need

Comment: @davide Could you please add the error that is being thrown? Also, did you try replacing `let i = index` with `index as i`? The syntax to set index value has been changed for Angular versions 5 and above.

Comment: @Thank you, I solved my problem, I added this in HTML:  `{{ annexeDetails?.TAB[5].LIB}}` and `{{ annexeDetails?.TAB[5].ZON}}` .